# Что значит Completed 204 No Content в Ruby

Tags: ruby, email

Что значит, если в log файле Ruby пишется после определенного процесса Completed 204 No Content вместо Completed 200 OK?
Определенный процесс - это отправка письма на почту. И кажется, что процесс прошёл неудачно, ведь обычно пишется в конце Completed 200 OK?

```
Rendered paydoc_mailer/item_destroyed.text.erb (0.0ms)

PaydocMailer#item_destroyed: processed outbound mail in 16.0ms

Sent mail to mail@gmail.com (4.0ms)
Date: Tue, 10 Oct 2017 16:41:09 +0300
From: test@mail.com
To: mail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <59dccdf5d6d56_c3412fa1e831488@PC.mail>
Subject: Test fgdfgg!
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

client_id 444
Completed 204 No Content in 129ms (ActiveRecord: 91.0ms)
```

Comment: 204 означает, что все прошло успешно, но нет тела ответа.

Comment: [Все HTTP-статусы от 200 до 299 означают разных видов успех](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#.D0.A3.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.85). Проверяйте свои предположения :)

Comment: О, спасибо за ссылку на статусы!
Но странно, что он не видит тело сообщения, ведь client_id 444 - это оно и есть, он его отобразил в логе.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в методе отправки, я указала в  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test вместо  :test -> :smtp, но сервер не перезагрузила, вот он и отправлял в тестовом режиме.
А так сообщение Completed 204 No Content действительно означает, что письмо успешно отправлено, но не содержит в себе файлов.

Comment: *Completed 204 No Content означает, что письмо успешно отправлено, но не содержит в себе файлов* -- нет, этого оно не означает. К письму этот статус не имеет отношения, он имеет отношение к ответу на HTTP-запрос, который совершил клиент. То, что этот запрос привёл к отправке письма (или просто логи так совпали), это уже совсем другая история.